# Highcharts: are multiple legends possible?

Tags: highcharts, legend

I'm new to Highcharts and it seems excellent this far. However, I need to have my six series grouped into three columns in the legend. This can be achieved by limiting legend width and using `legendIndex`. Config snippet of this in Coffeescript:

```
  legend:
    # 3 items side-by-side with some margins
    itemWidth: Math.floor(config.width / 3.8)
  series: [
      # top left
      legendIndex: 1
      ...
    ,
      # bottom left
      legendIndex: 4
      ...
    ...  # 4 more series; other columns in indices 2,5 and 3,6
    ]
```

**The problem** is, I also need a separate title for each group. So something like this (ascii art):

```
Title A               Title B                 Title C
[ ] Item A1           [ ] Item B1             [ ] Item C1
[ ] Item A2           [ ] Item B2             [ ] Item C2
```

Note that I need the export functionality as well, so HTML positioning is not possible as I understand it. How can I make my legend look like this?

Comment: Turns out I absolutely need multiple legends--groups with titles are not enough.

Comment: Have you tried to use labelFormatter and insidie funtion calculate when "title" should be added? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter

Comment: @SebastianBochan thanks for the input! I thought of this, but if I position the titles with `useHTML` the exports get messy.

Comment: Unortnately exported chart doesn't use html / css styles.

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833248/highcharts-multiple-legends, however the answer is also "not possible" there

Comment: You can create custom legend. Refer this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146206/group-series-names-in-columns-in-highchart-horizontal-legend

Answer (score 0):

You can place custom text on to the chart using the Highcharts Renderer

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

You can't make multiple legends, but you can do a lot with a single legend to make it look like multiple legends.