# Highcharts multiple legends

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've created a Highcharts chart, which has multiple Y-Axises and one X-Axis.

The Y-Axises are on different levels:

```
...
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
yAxis: [{
          height: 230,
          top: 70
        }, {
          height: 230,
          top: 394
      },
  ],
...
```

This way I have multiple graphs with just one time line which let me zoom all graphs at once. See http://jsfiddle.net/jnLAu/

I'd like to have multiple legends, one for each Y-Axis. Is there any way in Highcharts to create charts with multiple legends?

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you're looking for. I can see the legend on the chart, containing all your series?

Comment: I want to have a legend under each y-axis (totally 2 in the example above), containing only the series of one y-axis

Comment: I've never tried it this way.  I would have made 2 charts and then used the selection event (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.selection) to keep them in sync.  But, I like the way the tooltip spans both charts.

Comment: Why don't you create 2 charts ?

Comment: I need to have all values in one tooltip. Also the crosshair spanning over the whole chart is useful for inspecting the graph.

Comment: Highcharts supports only one legend per chart.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple legends, but there are a number of techniques you can use to make it look like you have more than one legend. For your example you can set

```
itemMarginBottom: 280
```

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jnLAu/