# R Highcharter: Clever way to separate legends or multiple charts with synchronized zoom/tooltip?

Tags: highcharts, zooming, legend, r-highcharter

My question relates to the case where I'm using highstock to plot multiple stacked y axes, such as in the last example here: http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highstock.html.

I would like to have separate legends for each of the y axes, but doing some digging it appears as though highcharts can have only one legend ([Highcharts multiple legends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833248/highcharts-multiple-legends)).

Then I thought maybe I could use annotations to mimic the desired legends. But drawing the colored line segments would be messy as they would show up as series (although I guess I could just use colored text to indicate which series is which).

Is there a clever way to get around the one-legend limitation when using multiple y axes in highcharts?

If not, then if I absolutely needed to have separate legends, I would seemingly have to use multiple stacked charts. In which case, I would need to synchronize the zoom and the tooltip across those multiple charts. There's lots of info on how to do this via javascript (which I have limited experience with), but there also seems to be recurring problems getting both the zoom and the tooltip to synchronize.

I was wondering if there are any examples on how to synchronize the zoom and tooltip across multiple charts in R highcharter (I've searched high and low and haven't been able to find any)?

I'd be extremely grateful for any insight the community here might have.

```
library(highcharter)
library(gplots)

dates   <- seq(as.Date('2015-04-24'),as.Date('2020-04-24'),1)
nDates  <- NROW(dates)
x11     <- xts(100 * cumprod(1 + 0.0010 * (1 + 0.0002 * rnorm(nDates))), dates)
x12     <- xts(100 * cumprod(1 + 0.0012 * (1 + 0.0001 * rnorm(nDates))), dates)
x2      <- xts(100 * runif(nDates), dates)
x31     <- xts(-1 + 2 * runif(nDates), dates)
x32     <- xts( 1 - 2 * runif(nDates), dates)

glc     <- col2hex('gray65') #gridLineColor)

hc <- highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
        hc_chart(marginLeft = 75, marginRight = 75) %>% 
        hc_title(text = 'Example', align = 'center', verticalAlign = 'top', style = list(fontWeight = 'bold', fontSize = '20px')) %>%
        hc_rangeSelector(selected = 7) %>%
        hc_navigator(series = list(color = hex_to_rgba('black',1))) %>%
        hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime') %>% 
        hc_yAxis_multiples( 
                            #yAxis = 0, plot x11 and x12 here
                            list(top = "0%",  height = '60%', opposite = FALSE, type = 'logarithmic', showLastLabel = TRUE, allowDecimals = FALSE, 
                                     labels = list(align = 'right', x = -10, format = '{value}%', distance = 0), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, startOnTick = FALSE, endOnTick = TRUE),

                            #yAxis = 1 to duplicate axis labels on opposite side    
                            list(top = "0%",  height = '60%', opposite = TRUE, type = 'logarithmic', showLastLabel = TRUE, allowDecimals = FALSE, linkedTo = 0, opposite = TRUE, 
                                labels = list(align = 'right', x =  50, format = '{value}%', distance = 0), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, startOnTick = FALSE, endOnTick = TRUE),

                            #yAxis = 2, just to separate the charts
                            list(top = '60%', height = '5%'),

                            #yAxis = 3, plot x2 here
                            list(top = '65%', height = '15%', opposite = FALSE, tickPositions = c(0, 33, 67, 100), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, showLastLabel = TRUE,
                                    labels = list(align = 'right', x= 35, format = '{value}%', distance = 0)),

                            #yAxis = 4, to duplicate the axis labels on the opposite side
                            list(top = '65%', height = '15%', linkedTo = 3, opposite = TRUE, tickPositions = c(0, 33, 67, 100), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, showLastLabel = TRUE,
                                        labels = list(align = 'right', x= 50, format = '{value}%', distance = 0)),

                            #yAxis = 5, to separate the charts
                            list(top = '80%', height = '5%'),

                            #yAxis = 6, plot x31, x32, x33 here
                            list(top = '85%', height = '15%', opposite = FALSE, tickPositions = c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, showLastLabel = TRUE,
                                    labels = list(align = 'right', x = 30, distance = 0, format = '{value:.1f}'), plotLines = list(list(color = "black", width = 2, value = 0))),

                            #yAxis = 7, to duplicate the axis labels on the opposite side
                            list(top = '85%', height = '15%', linkedTo = 6, opposite = TRUE, tickPositions = c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, showLastLabel = TRUE,
                                        labels = list(align = 'right', x = 50, distance = 0, format = '{value:.1f}'))

                          ) %>%


            #Chart 1
            hc_add_series(x11, yAxis = 0, color = 'navy',   name = 'Series 11', tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 1, valueSuffix = '%')) %>%  
            hc_add_series(x12, yAxis = 0, color = 'green',  name = 'Series 12', tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 1, valueSuffix = '%')) %>% 

            #Chart 2
            hc_add_series(x2, yAxis = 3, color = 'black', name = 'Series 2', tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 0, valueSuffix = '%')) %>%

            #Chart 3
            hc_add_series(x31,  yAxis = 6, color = 'blue',  name = 'Series 31', tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2)) %>%
            hc_add_series(x32,  yAxis = 6, color = 'green', name = 'Series 32', tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2)) %>%

            #Chart 'titles'
            hc_annotations(list(labels = list(  list(point = list(x = 0, y = 20),                       text = 'Chart 1',   backgroundColor = 'white', borderColor = 'white', color = 'black', style = list(fontWeight = 'bold')), 
                                                list(point = list(yAxis = 3, x = index(x)[1], y = 90),  text = 'Chart 2',   backgroundColor = 'white', borderColor = 'white', color = 'black', style = list(fontWeight = 'bold')), 
                                                list(point = list(yAxis = 7, x = index(x)[1], y = 0.9), text = 'Chart 3',   backgroundColor = 'white', borderColor = 'white', color = 'black', style = list(fontWeight = 'bold')))))

print(hc)
```

In the example above, ideally, one would be able to put separate legends on Chart 1 and Chart 3 where there are multiple series.

Comment: Hi! If I had to choose whether to try to create a custom legend or synchronize charts - I would go custom legend way. For now (we are working on multiple legends in Highcharts now, I hope we will finish soon and it will be a part of next release) but for now, in theory, you can have only one legend. But nothing stops you from creating a custom legend. If you provide me a mockup of how should it look like (sample Highcharter demo reproducible in RStudio would be helpful too) then I will help you achieve it or at least advise what exactly could be done.

Comment: @raf18seb I really appreciate your insight. It's encouraging that there is likely to be a solution in the future. Thank you. I've edited the post to show some example code that is basically everything I'm looking for (at the moment) minus some method to put separate legends on the charts that have more than one series (in the example above, Charts 1 and 3, which are on y axes 0 and 6, respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to set *legend.layout* to `proximate`, see the example:

```
library(highcharter)
library(gplots)
library(xts)

dates   <- seq(as.Date('2015-04-24'),as.Date('2020-04-24'),1)
nDates  <- NROW(dates)
x11     <- xts(100 * cumprod(1 + 0.0010 * (1 + 0.0002 * rnorm(nDates))), dates)
x12     <- xts(100 * cumprod(1 + 0.0012 * (1 + 0.0001 * rnorm(nDates))), dates)
x2      <- xts(100 * runif(nDates), dates)
x31     <- xts(-1 + 2 * runif(nDates), dates)
x32     <- xts( 1 - 2 * runif(nDates), dates)

glc     <- col2hex('gray65') #gridLineColor)

hc <- highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
  hc_chart(marginLeft = 150, marginRight = 75) %>% 
  hc_title(text = 'Example', align = 'center', verticalAlign = 'top', style = list(fontWeight = 'bold', fontSize = '20px')) %>%
  hc_rangeSelector(selected = 7) %>%
  hc_navigator(series = list(color = hex_to_rgba('black',1)), top = 580) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime') %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE, layout = 'proximate', align = 'left', floating = FALSE) %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples( 
    #yAxis = 0, plot x11 and x12 here
    list(top = "0%",  height = '60%', opposite = FALSE, type = 'logarithmic', showLastLabel = TRUE, allowDecimals = FALSE, 
         labels = list(align = 'right', x = -10, format = '{value}%', distance = 0), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, startOnTick = FALSE, endOnTick = TRUE),

    #yAxis = 1 to duplicate axis labels on opposite side    
    list(top = "0%",  height = '60%', opposite = TRUE, type = 'logarithmic', showLastLabel = TRUE, allowDecimals = FALSE, linkedTo = 0, opposite = TRUE, 
         labels = list(align = 'right', x =  50, format = '{value}%', distance = 0), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, startOnTick = FALSE, endOnTick = TRUE),

    #yAxis = 2, just to separate the charts
    list(top = '60%', height = '5%'),

    #yAxis = 3, plot x2 here
    list(top = '65%', height = '15%', opposite = FALSE, tickPositions = c(0, 33, 67, 100), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, showLastLabel = TRUE,
         labels = list(align = 'right', x= 35, format = '{value}%', distance = 0)),

    #yAxis = 4, to duplicate the axis labels on the opposite side
    list(top = '65%', height = '15%', linkedTo = 3, opposite = TRUE, tickPositions = c(0, 33, 67, 100), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, showLastLabel = TRUE,
         labels = list(align = 'right', x= 50, format = '{value}%', distance = 0)),

    #yAxis = 5, to separate the charts
    list(top = '80%', height = '5%'),

    #yAxis = 6, plot x31, x32, x33 here
    list(top = '85%', height = '15%', opposite = FALSE, tickPositions = c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, showLastLabel = TRUE,
         labels = list(align = 'right', x = 30, distance = 0, format = '{value:.1f}'), plotLines = list(list(color = "black", width = 2, value = 0))),

    #yAxis = 7, to duplicate the axis labels on the opposite side
    list(top = '85%', height = '15%', linkedTo = 6, opposite = TRUE, tickPositions = c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), gridLineDashStyle = 'Dot', gridLineColor = glc, showLastLabel = TRUE,
         labels = list(align = 'right', x = 50, distance = 0, format = '{value:.1f}'))

  ) %>%


  #Chart 1
  hc_add_series(x11, yAxis = 0, color = 'navy',   name = 'Series 11', tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 1, valueSuffix = '%')) %>%  
  hc_add_series(x12, yAxis = 0, color = 'green',  name = 'Series 12', tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 1, valueSuffix = '%')) %>% 

  #Chart 2
  hc_add_series(x2, yAxis = 3, color = 'black', name = 'Series 2', tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 0, valueSuffix = '%')) %>%

  #Chart 3
  hc_add_series(x31,  yAxis = 6, color = 'blue',  name = 'Series 31', tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2)) %>%
  hc_add_series(x32,  yAxis = 6, color = 'green', name = 'Series 32', tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2))


print(hc)
```

Unfortunately, there is a bug with this layout in Highstock. The navigator is placed incorrectly - I reported this bug here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13392

As a workaround, I suggest moving the navigator using *navigator.top* property, but it is not a perfect solution. We could change the core code and write the logic that would place the navigator correctly and automatically, but it requires some custom JavaScript coding.

If this solution doesn't meet your requirements, you could always render your legend items using Highcharts SVG Renderer tool, but it also requires some custom coding. You can find many examples of custom legend on official Highcharts Forum, StackOverflow, or you can see this article I wrote about Renderer usage: https://support.highcharts.com/support/solutions/articles/44001706971-how-to-use-highcharts-svg-renderer

Comment: thank you very much for that information, it was very useful. The use of legend.layout proximate does not quite work for me for this particular example, but you have pointed me on the right path and alerted me to a potential solution for multiple legends in future releases of highcharts. Much appreciated.

Comment: This is ticket with this enhancement: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11309 and this is PR https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/pull/12478 but it hasn't been accepted yet and merged into the Highcharts core

Comment: any idea on if or when the PR will be accepted and merged?

Comment: Unfortunately not. As far as I know, there are some compatibility issues with this module and it's waiting for some final decisions. You can ask this question directly in the GitHub ticket and you will get the answer directly from core developers working on this module.

Comment: @KamilKulig do you have more info?